# IF one cell is blank then next cell should show

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a problem that if A2 is blank then B1 should show and if b2 also blank then c1 should show and if c2 also blank then d1 should show.

So how can I create a formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't understand completely, but nested `IF()`s could do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested nested `IF()`s solution:

```
=IF(A2="",IF(B2="",IF(C2="",IF(D2="","",D$1),C$1),B$1),A$1)
```

For something a bit more scaleable, you could use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:D$1,MATCH("*",A2:D2,0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks LOT. You helped me so much. Now it's very easy & not wasting my time also.

Comment: Dear, again I have a problem on the formula =IF(A2="",IF(B2="",IF(C2="",IF(D2="","",D$1),C$1),B$1),A$1). I need to use this formula in 3 places. one by one. let's say A10, A11 & A12 I need to use the formula. if B1 is showing in A10, it shows in A11&A12 also. I need if B1 is showing in A10 then it should not show in A11 & A12. Please Help